# Why is javascript ajax return is opting for else condition even if the return is for first condition?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would appreciate it if you could help me figure out the problem with my code below .

Am trying to do a login using javascript ajax , for a **successful login** the return is **success** but the system when/ even if the return is **success** still the system is opting for **else** condition hence failing to do loggin .

**Please help me, what could be the problem?**

```
function login(){
    
    var staffno=document.getElementById('staffno').value;
    var password=document.getElementById('password').value;
    if(staffno=='' || password==''){
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<small><font color=red><b>all required</b></font></small>";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="<small><font color=purple><b>verifying...</b></font></small>";
    var formData=new FormData();
         formData.append('staffno',staffno);
         formData.append('password',password);
         formData.append('login','');
         var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
             if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
                 if(xhttp.responseText=='success'){
                 document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='<small><font color=green><b>verified, loging in...</b></font></small>';
                 window.location='dashboard.php';
                }else{
                 document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;   
                }
            }
         }
         xhttp.open('POST','processor.php',true);
         xhttp.send(formData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `if` obviously cannot fail, it is something related to the value in `xhttp.responseText`. It either has a typo and doesn't match `success`, or there is an additional character somewhere that makes returned value not match your `success` value. I would `console.log` the incoming value and copy-pasted it instead of your `success` word.

Comment: Thanks code worked after runing console.log